# Show list of open ports using firewalld in CentOS7

Tags: centos, firewalld

Is there an easy way to show a full list of all the ports that have been opened using `firewalld`?

I know the command `firewall-cmd --list-all`, but that just shows service names, not the ports that those services define as being open.

For example:

```
[root@myserver log]# firewall-cmd --list-all
  dmz (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources: 
  services: ssh squid my-icap 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I know I can go into the definition files for each of these services to see what ports they are defining as open, but it seems like there should be a single-line way to do this, and I'm just missing it.

And I'm not looking for `netstat`: that will tell me if something is listening on a port, which is a different question from whether that port is accessible from another host.

Comment: Did you open the ports with `firewall-cmd --add-port` or `firewall-cmd --add-service`?

Comment: With `--add-service`, which is why they show up in the `services:` line. If I had added the ports individually with `--add-port`, then they would have shown up in the `ports:` line. But I like the concept of grouping ports by service and enabling and disabling them all together, I'm just frustrated that I can't find a simple way to see all the ports that are opened by the listed services.

Comment: Then that's your answer. When you use `--add-services`,  the `--list-all` switch only shows the services. That's the way that `firewall-cmd` is designed to work. If you want it to list the ports then you'll either have to open them with `--add-port` or edit the code of `firewall-cmd` so that it shows the ports as well as the services.

Comment: I understand that that's the way that the `--list-all` option works. It just seems bizarre if there's no way to display all the ports that are open, which - surely - is one of the most common questions about a firewall's status. Even `--service <service_name> get-ports` doesn't give the information about a single service.

Comment: I completely agree with you @DaveMulligan and I'm looking for exactly same thing but can't find it and because here's no answer I guess no one knows...

Comment: I as well would like to see all the open ports on a screen for my own piece of mind.  From a Security Auditing perspective.

Answer (score 13):

I've also been looking for this, currently I came up with this bash oneliner

```bash
for s in $(firewall-cmd --list-services); do firewall-cmd --permanent --service "$s" --get-ports; done;
```

and for regular ports just use

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

or just

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should work for both direct-interface services and rich language rules, and show the service name along with its port numbers, protocols, etc.

```shell
firewall-cmd --list-all | egrep "services|service.*accept" | sed -e 's/.*="\(.*\)".*/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\s\+services:\s\+//g' | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I '{}' firewall-cmd --info-service={}
```

If you just want something easy to remember, to ad-hoc lookup the port definitions for a service, then:

```
firewall-cmd --info-service=service_name
```