# Is there a way to check the ports that are open in firewalld without sudo?

Tags: rhel, firewalld

I noticed that even checking the status of `firewalld` seems to require `sudo`. I want to keep the privileges of this script as low as possible and, for that reason, I would like the user to be able to check the port status as a regular user. If necessary, they can then request escalation to `sudo`.

Is it possible to achieve this on a RHEL-based system, or do you need to be `sudo` for all of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**visudo**

To check open ports with `firewalld` this requires administrative privileges sudo.

It's not a very clean way, but you can edit the `sudoers` file with:

`sudo visudo`

Add this and replace `USER` with the username you want to grant permissions to:

`<USER> ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/firewall-cmd --list-ports`

This grants the `USER` permission to execute the `firewall-cmd --list-ports` command.

It is important to caution when modifying system configurations and granting permissions!

[How to List Open Ports in Firewalld](https://linuxhint.com/list_open_ports_firewalld/)

[Show list of open ports using firewalld in CentOS7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536694/show-list-of-open-ports-using-firewalld-in-centos7)

[Exit/save edit to sudoers file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736351/exit-save-edit-to-sudoers-file-putty-ssh#:%7E:text=To%20make%20changes%20to%20sudo%20from%20putty%2Fbash%3A%201,press%20esc%20to%20exit%20editing%20mode.%20Weitere%20Elemente)

[How to Edit Sudoers File in Linux](https://operavps.com/docs/edit-sudoers-file/)

[How to Use Sudo and the Sudoers File](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/sudo-and-the-sudoers-file/)

**setuid**

You can create a script that runs with elevated privileges with `setuid`.

> Using the setuid or setgid bit on a shell script will create more problems—especially security problems—than it solves. **Some systems (such as Linux) don’t even honor the setuid bit on shell scripts, so creating setuid shell scripts creates an unnecessary portability problem in addition to the security risks.**

[setuid(2) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)

[Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

[Why do my setuid root bash shell scripts not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565729/why-do-my-setuid-root-bash-shell-scripts-not-work)

[How to use the "setuid" bit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543002/how-to-use-the-setuid-bit)

[Writing setuid or setgid Scripts](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/bash-cookbook/0596526784/ch14s15.html)

**Both solutions should only be used with caution and with the greatest care!**

**For security reasons, it is recommended to perform the check for open ports with `firewalld` at the end using either the `root` user or a user with administrative rights.**